# Php read excel file which have non english content using PHPExcel lib

Tags: php, excel

I have a xlsx file which contain non English content (Russian). I'm using PHPExcel lib to read it. When I read my file the out put is totally messed up ? is there any way to fix this ? I tried to convert utf8 but no luck. Any help would be appreciate . Here is my code.

```
<?php 
include_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
echo '<pre>';

$excelFile = "test.xlsx";

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excelFile);

//Itrating through all the sheets in the excel workbook and storing the array data
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    $arrayData[$worksheet->getTitle()] = $worksheet->toArray();
}

/* function utf8_converter($arrayData)
{
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    });

        return $arrayData;
}
utf8_converter($arrayData);
 */

print_r($arrayData);

?>
```

My output is ,

```
[1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 199
                    [1] => Clothing
                    [2] => ru
                    [3] => T shirt
                    [4] => Ð‘ÐµÑÐ¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð´Ñ‡Ð¸Ðº , Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð´ , Ð‘ÐµÑÐ¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€ÑŒ Ð˜Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚
                    [5] => Ð‘ÐµÑÐ¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð´Ñ‡Ð¸Ðº , Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð´ , Ð‘ÐµÑÐ¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€ÑŒ Ð˜Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 203
                    [1] => Clothing
                    [2] => ru
                    [3] => pant
                    [4] => Ð‘ÐµÑÐ¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð´Ñ‡Ð¸Ðº , Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð´ , Ð‘ÐµÑÐ¿Ð»Ð°Ñ‚Ð½Ñ‹Ð¹ ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ€ÑŒ Ð˜Ð½Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð½ÐµÑ‚
                    [5] => This test Short des
                )
```

But the original value is like,

```
Бесплатный переводчик , перевод , Бесплатный словарь Интернет
```

Comment: Where is this outputting to? A console? A web page?

Comment: If you're outputting to a web page, make sure that it's set to display UTF-8 content

Comment: The data from PHPExcel should already be UTF-8 (no further conversion necessary), you need to ensure that your browser is correctly set to display UTF-8

Comment: @MarkBaker I have tried in all browsers but same result only i got ...

Comment: Have you any html output that tells the browser that it's going to be getting UTF-8 content? e.g. a `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` block or similar?

Comment: Either that or add the statement `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')` at the top of your script.

Comment: The logic behind in this is I need to save this content in db. It is saved in correctly in DB. Only problem in browser. So my problem is solved..!.

Comment: Oh..yes..! How I missed this ..? Thanks Phylogenesis and  Mark Baker

Answer (score -1):

Find `fputcsv` (or similar function for xlsx) call in your excel library code. Enable all necessary parameters to it

int fputcsv (resource $handle , 
              array $fields [, 
              string $delimiter = "," [,
              string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape_char = "\" ]]] )

Then use,

```
$text = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;
```

Here out_charset plays an important role.

If you append the string //TRANSLIT to out_charset transliteration is activated. This means that when a character can't be represented in the target charset, it can be approximated through one or several similarly looking characters. If you append the string //IGNORE, characters that cannot be represented in the target charset are silently discarded. Otherwise, E_NOTICE is generated and the function will return FALSE.

```
ISO 8859:

ISO 8859-1 Western Europe
ISO 8859-2 Western and Central Europe
ISO 8859-3 Western Europe and South European (Turkish, Maltese plus Esperanto)
ISO 8859-4 Western Europe and Baltic countries (Lithuania, Estonia, Latvia and Lapp)
ISO 8859-5 Cyrillic alphabet
ISO 8859-6 Arabic
ISO 8859-7 Greek
ISO 8859-8 Hebrew
ISO 8859-9 Western Europe with amended Turkish character set
ISO 8859-10 Western Europe with rationalised character set for Nordic languages, including complete Icelandic set
ISO 8859-11 Thai
ISO 8859-13 Baltic languages plus Polish
ISO 8859-14 Celtic languages (Irish Gaelic, Scottish, Welsh)
ISO 8859-15 Added the Euro sign and other rationalisations to ISO 8859-1
ISO 8859-16 Central, Eastern and Southern European languages (Albanian, Bosnian, Croatian, Hungarian, Polish, Romanian, Serbian and Slovenian, but also French, German, Italian and Irish Gaelic)
```

and more charset Google it...

Check for more info,

```
[http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php][1]

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding][2]
```

Comment: This isn't simply reading a CSV file.... it's reading an OfficeOpenXML-format spreadsheet file